# fastest packing of data in Python (and Java)

Tags: java, python, performance, optimization, serialization

<sub>([Sometimes](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html) our host is wrong; nanoseconds matter ;)</sub>

I have a Python Twisted server that talks to some Java servers and profiling shows spending ~30% of its runtime in the JSON encoder/decoder; its job is handling thousands of messages per second.

[This talk](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/3/26/7-years-of-youtube-scalability-lessons-in-30-minutes.html) by youtube raises interesting applicable points:

- Serialization formats - no matter which one you use, they are all
  expensive. Measure. Don’t use pickle. Not a good choice. Found
  protocol buffers slow. They wrote their own BSON implementation which
  is 10-15 time faster than the one you can download.
- You have to measure. Vitess swapped out one its protocols for an HTTP
  implementation. Even though it was in C it was slow. So they ripped
  out HTTP and did a direct socket call using python and that was 8%
  cheaper on global CPU. The enveloping for HTTP is really expensive.
- Measurement. In Python measurement is like reading tea leaves.
  There’s a lot of things in Python that are counter intuitive, like
  the cost of grabage colleciton. Most of chunks of their apps spend
  their time serializing. Profiling serialization is very depending on
  what you are putting in. Serializing ints is very different than
  serializing big blobs.

Anyway, I control both the Python and Java ends of my message-passing API and can pick a different serialisation than JSON.

My messages look like:

- a variable number of longs; anywhere between 1 and 10K of them
- and two already-UTF8 text strings; both between 1 and 3KB

Because I am reading them from a socket, I want libraries that can cope gracefully with streams - its irritating if it doesn't tell me how much of a buffer it consumed, for example.

The other end of this stream is a Java server, of course; I don't want to pick something that is great for the Python end but moves problems to the Java end e.g. performance or torturous or flaky API.

I will obviously be doing my own profiling.  I ask here in the hope you describe approaches I wouldn't think of e.g. using [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) and what the fastest kind of strings/buffers are.

Some simple test code gives surprising results:

```
import time, random, struct, json, sys, pickle, cPickle, marshal, array

def encode_json_1(*args):
    return json.dumps(args)

def encode_json_2(longs,str1,str2):
    return json.dumps({"longs":longs,"str1":str1,"str2":str2})

def encode_pickle(*args):
    return pickle.dumps(args)

def encode_cPickle(*args):
    return cPickle.dumps(args)

def encode_marshal(*args):
    return marshal.dumps(args)

def encode_struct_1(longs,str1,str2):
    return struct.pack(">iii%dq"%len(longs),len(longs),len(str1),len(str2),*longs)+str1+str2

def decode_struct_1(s):
    i, j, k = struct.unpack(">iii",s[:12])
    assert len(s) == 3*4 + 8*i + j + k, (len(s),3*4 + 8*i + j + k)
    longs = struct.unpack(">%dq"%i,s[12:12+i*8])
    str1 = s[12+i*8:12+i*8+j]
    str2 = s[12+i*8+j:]
    return (longs,str1,str2)

struct_header_2 = struct.Struct(">iii")

def encode_struct_2(longs,str1,str2):
    return "".join((
        struct_header_2.pack(len(longs),len(str1),len(str2)),
        array.array("L",longs).tostring(),
        str1,
        str2))

def decode_struct_2(s):
    i, j, k = struct_header_2.unpack(s[:12])
    assert len(s) == 3*4 + 8*i + j + k, (len(s),3*4 + 8*i + j + k)
    longs = array.array("L")
    longs.fromstring(s[12:12+i*8])
    str1 = s[12+i*8:12+i*8+j]
    str2 = s[12+i*8+j:]
    return (longs,str1,str2)

def encode_ujson(*args):
    return ujson.dumps(args)

def encode_msgpack(*args):
    return msgpacker.pack(args)

def decode_msgpack(s):
    msgunpacker.feed(s)
    return msgunpacker.unpack()

def encode_bson(longs,str1,str2):
    return bson.dumps({"longs":longs,"str1":str1,"str2":str2})

def from_dict(d):
    return [d["longs"],d["str1"],d["str2"]]

tests = [ #(encode,decode,massage_for_check)
    (encode_struct_1,decode_struct_1,None),
    (encode_struct_2,decode_struct_2,None),
    (encode_json_1,json.loads,None),
    (encode_json_2,json.loads,from_dict),
    (encode_pickle,pickle.loads,None),
    (encode_cPickle,cPickle.loads,None),
    (encode_marshal,marshal.loads,None)]

try:
    import ujson
    tests.append((encode_ujson,ujson.loads,None))
except ImportError:
    print "no ujson support installed"

try:
    import msgpack
    msgpacker = msgpack.Packer()
    msgunpacker = msgpack.Unpacker()
    tests.append((encode_msgpack,decode_msgpack,None))
except ImportError:
    print "no msgpack support installed"

try:
    import bson
    tests.append((encode_bson,bson.loads,from_dict))
except ImportError:
    print "no BSON support installed"

longs = [i for i in xrange(10000)]
str1 = "1"*5000
str2 = "2"*5000

random.seed(1)
encode_data = [[
        longs[:random.randint(2,len(longs))],
        str1[:random.randint(2,len(str1))],
        str2[:random.randint(2,len(str2))]] for i in xrange(1000)]

for encoder,decoder,massage_before_check in tests:
    # do the encoding
    start = time.time()
    encoded = [encoder(i,j,k) for i,j,k in encode_data]
    encoding = time.time()
    print encoder.__name__, "encoding took %0.4f,"%(encoding-start),
    sys.stdout.flush()
    # do the decoding
    decoded = [decoder(e) for e in encoded]
    decoding = time.time()
    print "decoding %0.4f"%(decoding-encoding)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    # check it
    if massage_before_check:
        decoded = [massage_before_check(d) for d in decoded]
    for i,((longs_a,str1_a,str2_a),(longs_b,str1_b,str2_b)) in enumerate(zip(encode_data,decoded)):
        assert longs_a == list(longs_b), (i,longs_a,longs_b)
        assert str1_a == str1_b, (i,str1_a,str1_b)
        assert str2_a == str2_b, (i,str2_a,str2_b)
```

gives:

```
encode_struct_1 encoding took 0.4486, decoding 0.3313
encode_struct_2 encoding took 0.3202, decoding 0.1082
encode_json_1 encoding took 0.6333, decoding 0.6718
encode_json_2 encoding took 0.5740, decoding 0.8362
encode_pickle encoding took 8.1587, decoding 9.5980
encode_cPickle encoding took 1.1246, decoding 1.4436
encode_marshal encoding took 0.1144, decoding 0.3541
encode_ujson encoding took 0.2768, decoding 0.4773
encode_msgpack encoding took 0.1386, decoding 0.2374
encode_bson encoding took 55.5861, decoding 29.3953
```

[bson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bson/0.3.3), [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) and [ujson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson/) all installed via easy_install

I would *love* to be shown I'm doing it wrong; that I should be using cStringIO interfaces or however else you speed it all up!

There must be a way to serialise this data that is an order of magnitude faster surely?

Comment: for serialization at the python end, you can use cpickle as it is more than 10X faster than pickle. At the server side, you can use StringBuilder (if you are looking for optimization, and do not need concurrent access)

Comment: I am not sure if replacing json with something else is a good idea. If the python end would've been in jython, then serialization in java would have been execellent idea.

Comment: Why not try a simple delimited string. "1|2|3|4|foo|bar" if you can find a delimiter that never appears in your string values then using String.Split would be the fastest 'deserialization'

Comment: pickle/cPickle can actually do much better than your test results show, if you use the binary protocol.  Just change .dumps(args) to .dumps(args, -1) or .dumps(args, cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL).  When I rerun your benchmarks with those modifications, cPickle is actually able to beat msgpack for combined encode/decode time.  I realize that for Java interoperability, pickle isn't an option, but if you are only using Python and can trust your data (because pickle can be made to execute arbitrary code), it may very well be fast enough.

Comment: if speed matters then size also matters - the fewer bytes it takes to communicate information, the more information you can move in the same amount of time. msgpack beats all these options for size in the tests you've provided here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end, we chose to use msgpack.

If you go with JSON, your choice of library on Python and Java is critical to performance:

On Java, http://blog.juicehub.com/2012/11/20/benchmarking-web-frameworks-for-games/ says:

> Performance was absolutely atrocious until we swapped out the JSON Lib (json-simple) for Jackon’s ObjectMapper. This brought RPS for 35 to 300+ – a 10x increase

Answer (score 6):

While JSon is flexible, it is one of the slowest serialization formats in Java (possible python as well) in nano-seconds matter I would use a binary format in native byte order (likely to be little endian)

Here is a library were I do exactly that [AbstractExcerpt](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle/blob/master/src/main/java/vanilla/java/chronicle/impl/AbstractExcerpt.java) and [UnsafeExcerpt](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle/blob/master/src/main/java/vanilla/java/chronicle/impl/UnsafeExcerpt.java) A typical message takes 50 to 200 ns to serialize and send or read and deserialize.

Comment: Hmmm the slowest? I don't think XML is faster - from my experience it is slower and extremally resource-consuming.

Comment: XML is slower if you use a document model, but I have found it faster if you use a event model. It could have been the JSon encoder, decoder I was using. ;)

Comment: Interesting, maybe you've used JSon library that was operating on DOM-like structures, I think event-processing JSON would be faster, I must do some tests when I'll have time off.

Comment: I would be interested in the results.

Comment: You may find this more up to date link interesting http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2015/08/using-json-in-low-latency-environment.html?m=1

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to speed up the struct case

```
def encode_struct(longs,str1,str2):
    return struct.pack(">iii%dq"%len(longs),len(longs),len(str1),len(str2),*longs)+str1+str2
```

1. Try using the python array module and the method tostring to convert your longs into a binary string. Then you can append it like you did with the strings
2. Create a `struct.Struct` object and use that. I believe it's more efficient

You can also look into:

http://docs.python.org/library/xdrlib.html#module-xdrlib

Your fastest method encodes 1000 elements in .1222 seconds. That's 1 element in .1222 milliseconds. That's pretty fast. I doubt you'll do much better without switching languages.

Comment: Indeed it does, thanks!  I'm a bit hesitant, feeling I don't trust the array.tostring to be in a portable, dependable, defined format sadly

Comment: Necro alert: 12 years later and xdrlib is now deprecated by https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#xdrlib

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but it is still interesting. My most recent choice was to use [Cap’n Proto](https://capnproto.org/), written by the same guy who did protobuf for google. In my case, that lead to a decrease in both time and volume around 20% compared to Jackson's JSON encoder/decoder (server to server, Java on both sides).

Comment: Also see https://github.com/google/flatbuffers. Very interesting way to do this kind of thing

Answer (score 2):

[Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) are pretty fast and have bindings for both Java and Python. It's quite a popular library and used inside Google so it should be tested and optimized quite well.

Comment: the sources from Google cited in the question say they found protocol buffers slow; do you have stats for protocol buffer performance?

Comment: @Will "Fast" is relative. I've found Protocol Buffers faster than simple XML, and that was good enough for my use case. For some other use case, you may find that's not enough. It all depends on what exactly you need to do and what expectations you have.

Comment: Fast as in absolute "take least time for same work" kind of fast ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since the data your sending is already well defined, non-recursive, and non-nested, why not just use a simple delimited string. You just need a delimiter that isn't contained in your string variables maybe '\n'.

```
"10\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\nFoo Foo Foo\nBar Bar Bar"
```

Then just use a simple String Split method.

```
string[] temp = str.split("\n");
ArrayList<long> longs = new ArrayList<long>(long.parseLong(temp[0]));
string string1 = temp[temp.length-2];
string string2 = temp[temp.length-1];
for(int i = 1; i < temp.length-2 ; i++)
    longs.add(long.parseLong(temp[i]));
```

*note* The above was written in the web browser and untested so syntax errors may exist.

For a text based; I'd assume the above is the fastest method.