# can msgpack provide better performance and identical functionality of python's struct.pack()?

Tags: python, c++, c, udp, msgpack

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884080/fastest-packing-of-data-in-python-and-java) compares a number of serialization routines and indicates msgpack is faster that Python's `struct.pack()` and unpack() routines. I'd like to use msgpack but cannot figure out how to use `msgpack.packb()` for floats or doubles in an equivalent way as `struct.pack()`.

I need to send N doubles via udp from **python** to a **C/C++** listener that reads N doubles via udp/ip. The C/C++ listener cannot be modified. The Python `struct.pack()` method works well like this clip for packing N=3 doubles:

```
import struct
import msgpack

packer = struct.Struct('ddd')
myTuple = (1.1, 2.2, 3.3)
packedData = packer.pack(*myTuple)
```

print(packedData) yields:

```
b'\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xf1?\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\x01@ffffff\n@'
```

Then trying the same thing with msgpack:

```
msgPackedData = msgpack.packb(myTuple)
```

and print(msgPackedData) yields:

```
b'\x93\xcb?\xf1\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9a\xcb@\x01\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9a\xcb@\nffffff'
```

The outputs are clearly not the same. Packets sent with struct.pack() are interpreted properly by the udp listener perfectly, but I'd like to gain the performance improvement of msgpack.

Can the performance of msgpack be gained while producing identical output as `struct.pack()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compare two packed binaries.

The upper row is `msgPackedData` and the lower row is `packedData`.

```
0x93 0xcb 0x3f 0xf1 0x99 0x99 0x99 0x99 0x99 0x9a 0xcb 0x40 0x01 0x99 0x99 0x99 0x99 0x99 0x9a 0xcb 0x40 0x0a 0x66 0x66 0x66 0x66 0x66 0x66 
          0x9a 0x99 0x99 0x99 0x99 0x99 0xf1 0x3f      0x9a 0x99 0x99 0x99 0x99 0x99 0x01 0x40      0x66 0x66 0x66 0x66 0x66 0x66 0x0a 0x40
```

You can see the first 0x93 and three 0xcb. What is this?

MessagePack contains type information.

0x93 means the array of 3 elements. https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#array-format-family

0xcb means a big-endian
  IEEE 754 double precision floating point number https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#float-format-family

Therefore `msgPackedData` is 4bytes larger than `packedData`.

The other difference between `packedData` and `msgPackedData` is byte order. But it does not affect to the size.

If you don't use tuple, and simply pack three double numbers, then you can remove first 0x93. But there is no way to remove 0xcb. It is the only way to express double number in MessagePack format.

Comment: so the answer is, no, there's no way to generate equivalent output as 'struct.pack()' using msgpack?   I'm surprised that options such as binary and raw do not provide a means for identical results

Comment: it seems the performance benefits of msgpack are realized only when packing and unpacking on both ends

Comment: As you commented, the answer is "no". It seems that when we use `struct.pack()`, we need to know the complete type information and it should be matched at both ends. msgpack is different. It contains the type information like JSON. If the receive end doesn't know about the contents, they can treat the data some extent. e.g. creating JSON output. I think that if you chooose the msgpack as something like efficient JSON, it is good. See https://msgpack.org/ . If you want to the smallest packing way, msgpack is not good. I think that it is a flexibility/size choice.